# Hazelcast 2.5 Concurrency issues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are running hazelcast 2.5 as a cluster to replicate objects through applications. There are, at the moment, one producer and 3 consumers. The updates from the writer go as high as 10000 per minute and the consumers read every second searching for updates in the clustered map.The writer is a java native application running under a Debian 8 server with java 7. The hazelcast server is on the same machine as the producer but on an independent application. All the consumers are tomcat 7 apps running under a Debian 8 machine with java 7. The problem we are facing is that in average about 4 percent of the data clustered is reaching the consumer´s end garbled in the shared map. The code for the producer is the following :

```
        Long imei;
    Integer clase;
    HazelCastobjGpsData datoGps;
    HazelCastobjTelemetria datoTelemetria;
    Set<HazelCastpkQueue> keys = HazelCast.tmpQueue.keySet();
    for (Iterator<HazelCastpkQueue> i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        HazelCastpkQueue current = i.next();
        clase = current.getClase();
        imei = current.getImei();
        if (clase == CLASE_GPS) // GPS
        {
            try {
                HazelCast.clienteHC.getLock(imei).lock();

                datoGps = (HazelCastobjGpsData) HazelCast.tmpQueue
                        .remove(current);
                HazelCast.instMapGPS.put(current.getImei(), datoGps);
                HazelCast.instQueue.put(new HazelCastpkQueue(imei,
                        CLASE_GPS), CLASE_GPS);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Error HazelCast Gps Update: " + imei
                        + " :" + t.getMessage());
                if (!HazelCast.clienteHC.isActive()) {
                    System.out.println("Hazelcast no activo");
                }
            } finally {
                HazelCast.clienteHC.getLock(imei).unlock();
            }
        } else // Telemetria
        {
            try {
                HazelCast.clienteHC.getLock(imei).lock();
                datoTelemetria = (HazelCastobjTelemetria) HazelCast.tmpQueue
                        .remove(current);
                HazelCast.instMapTelemetria.put(new HazelCastpkQueue(imei,
                        clase), datoTelemetria);
                HazelCast.instQueue.put(new HazelCastpkQueue(imei, clase),
                        clase);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Error HazelCast Telemetria Update: "
                        + imei + " :" + t.getMessage());
                if (!HazelCast.clienteHC.isActive()) {
                    System.out.println("Hazelcast no activo");
                }
            } finally {
                HazelCast.clienteHC.getLock(imei).unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Where HazelCastobjGpsData datoGps; is the object to be rescued by the consumers and HazelCast.instMapGPS.put(current.getImei(), datoGps); is the map with problems. It has a long as a key.

The code for the server is the following:

```
public class HazelServer {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static ConcurrentMap<Long,HazelCastobjGpsData> instMapGPS;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static ConcurrentMap<HazelCastpkQueue,HazelCastobjTelemetria> instMapTelemetria;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static ConcurrentMap<HazelCastpkQueue,Integer> instQueue;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static BlockingQueue<HazelCastpkTisPanicoQueue> tisPanicQueue;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("HazelCast Server init 03/03/2015");
    init();
    System.out.println("OK");
}

private static void init() {
    try {
        HazelcastInstance hcServer = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(null);
        instMapGPS = hcServer.getMap("gps");
        instMapTelemetria = hcServer.getMap("telemetria");
        instQueue = hcServer.getMap("colagpstele");
        tisPanicQueue = hcServer.getQueue("cola_panico_tis");

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Error al tratar de obtener mapas: " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

The consumers code is the following

```
public static void fetchHazelCast() {

try {
    if (GetHazelCast.isHazelcastActive()) {
    double errores = 0;
    double count=0; 
    Set<HazelCastpkQueue> keys = GetHazelCast.hcQueue.keySet();
    for (final Iterator<HazelCastpkQueue> i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        HazelCastpkQueue currentKey = i.next();
        if (currentKey.getClase() == CLASE_GPS) // GPS Base
        {
        if(Realtime.newGPS(GetHazelCast.hcGPS.get(currentKey.getImei()))){
            errores++;
        }
        count++;
        } else // Telemetria
        {
        Realtime.newTelemetria(GetHazelCast.hcTelemetria.get(currentKey));
        }
        //count++;

        GetHazelCast.hcQueue.remove(currentKey);


        currentKey = null;
    }
    /*ReqInit.logger.warn("Errores "+(double)errores);
    ReqInit.logger.warn("Cantidad "+(double)count);
    ReqInit.logger.warn("Porcentaje "+(double) ((((double)errores)*100.0f)/(double)count));*/
    if(count>0){

            double promedio = (double) ((((double)errores)*100.0f)/(double)count);
            CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric("metricasreq", "errores",  errores);
            CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric("metricasreq", "cantidad",  count);
            CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric("metricasreq", "erroresporcentaje", promedio);
    }

    keys = null;
    } else {
    System.out.println("Hazelcast no activo...");
    GetHazelCast.contectarHZRealTime();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

note that the consumer only takes out the data that has been updated recently, this is done because there is a map whith keys that are been updated, once the data is out thar key is removed from that map.

The following is the code of the object

```
public class HazelCastobjGpsData implements DataSerializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Calendar utc;
    private Calendar lastupdate;
    private String now = "n/a";
    private double latitud = 0.0, longitud = 0.0, altitud = 0.0,
            velocidad = 0.0, cog = 0.0, nsat = 4.0, hdop = 2.0, adc1 = -200,
            adc2 = -200, adc3 = -200, adc4 = -200, bateria = -1;
    private int ignicion, io1 = -1, io2 = -1, io3 = -1, io4 = -1, power = -1,
            antirobo = -1, panico = -1;
    private long imei = 0L, driverId = -1;
    private boolean valid = true;
    private long odometro = -1L;
    private long horometro = -1L;
    private String ip = "N/A";

    private long ibutton2 = -1;
    private long ibutton3 = -1;
    private long ibutton4 = -1;
    private long odometroInterno = -1L;

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    private double anterior_lat = 0.0;
    private double anterior_lon = 0.0;
    private double anterior_sog = 0;
    private double anterior_cog = 0;
    private double anterior_ignicion = 0;
    private long anterior_odometro = 0;
    private long anterior_horometro = 0;
    private long delta_time = 0;
    private double delta_dist = 0;

    private long trailerId = -1L;
    private long tripTime = 0L;
    private long horometroInterno = 0L;

    public long getHorometroInterno() {
        return horometroInterno;
    }

    public void setHorometroInterno(long horometroInterno) {
        this.horometroInterno = horometroInterno;
    }

    public void setAnterior(HazelCastobjGpsData anterior) {
        this.setDelta_dist(Math.round((new Geo(this.latitud, this.longitud)
                .distanceKM(new Geo(anterior.getLatitud(), anterior
                        .getLongitud()))) * 1000));
        this.setDelta_time((this.getUTC().getTimeInMillis() - anterior.getUTC()
                .getTimeInMillis()) / 1000);
        this.setAnterior_cog(anterior.getCOG());
        this.setAnterior_sog(anterior.getVelocidad());
        this.setAnterior_lat(anterior.getLatitud());
        this.setAnterior_lon(anterior.getLongitud());
        this.setAnterior_ignicion(anterior.getIgnicion());
    }

    private boolean fromDB = false;

    private int evento = 0; // Por tiempo, curva u otro

    public Calendar getUTC() {
        return utc;
    }

    public String getNow() {
        return now;
    }

    public double getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }

    public double getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }

    public double getAltitud() {
        return altitud;
    }

    public double getVelocidad() {
        return velocidad;
    }

    public double getCOG() {
        return cog;
    }

    public String getCOGtoString() {
        String txtDireccion = "";
        if ((this.cog >= 0) && (this.cog <= 5)) {
            txtDireccion = "Norte";
        } else if ((this.cog > 5) && (this.cog <= 85)) {
            txtDireccion = "Noreste (NorOriente)";
        }

        else if ((this.cog > 85) && (this.cog <= 95)) {
            txtDireccion = "Este (Oriente)";
        } else if ((this.cog > 95) && (this.cog <= 175)) {
            txtDireccion = "Sureste (SurOriente)";
        }

        else if ((this.cog > 175) && (this.cog <= 185)) {
            txtDireccion = "Sur";
        }

        else if ((this.cog > 185) && (this.cog <= 265)) {
            txtDireccion = "Suroeste (SurPoniente)";
        } else if ((this.cog > 265) && (this.cog <= 275)) {
            txtDireccion = "Oeste (Poniente)";
        } else if ((this.cog > 275) && (this.cog <= 355)) {
            txtDireccion = "Noroeste (NorPoniente)";
        }

        else if ((this.cog > 355) && (this.cog <= 360)) {
            txtDireccion = "Norte";
        }

        return txtDireccion;
    }

    public double getNsat() {
        return nsat;
    }

    public double getHdop() {
        return hdop;
    }

    public double getAdc1() {
        return adc1;
    }

    public double getAdc2() {
        return adc2;
    }

    public double getBateria() {
        return bateria;
    }

    public int getIgnicion() {
        return ignicion;
    }

    public int getIo(int index) {
        int io_array[] = { 0, this.io1, this.io2, this.io3, this.io4,this.panico };
        return io_array[index];
    }

    public int getIo1() {
        return io1;
    }

    public int getIo2() {
        return io2;
    }

    public int getIo3() {
        return io3;
    }

    public int getIo4() {
        return io4;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public long getHorometro() {
        return horometro;
    }

    public long getOdometro() {
        return odometro;
    }

    public int getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public int getAntirobo() {
        return antirobo;
    }

    public int getPanico() {
        return panico;
    }

    public long getImei() {
        return imei;
    }

    public long getDriverId() {
        return driverId;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public Calendar getLastupdate() {
        return lastupdate;
    }

    public void setLastupdate(Calendar lastupdate) {
        this.lastupdate = lastupdate;
    }

    public HazelCastobjGpsData() {
    }

    public HazelCastobjGpsData(final GpsData original) {
        this.imei = original.getImei();
        this.driverId = original.getDriverId();
        this.panico = original.getPanico();
        this.antirobo = original.getAntirobo();
        this.ignicion = original.getIgnicion();
        this.now = original.getNow();
        this.ip = original.getIpaddress();

        if (original.getDriverIdArray() != null
                && original.getDriverIdArray().length == 4) {
            this.ibutton2 = original.getDriverIdArray()[1];
            this.ibutton3 = original.getDriverIdArray()[2];
            this.ibutton4 = original.getDriverIdArray()[3];
        } else {
            this.ibutton2 = -1;
            this.ibutton3 = -1;
            this.ibutton4 = -1;
        }

        if (original.getTimeCalendar() == null || !original.isFullProcessed()
                || original.isOnlyStatus()) {
            this.valid = false;
            Calendar fecha_gps = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                    .getTimeZone("UTC"));
            fecha_gps.setTimeInMillis(0);
            this.utc = fecha_gps;
            this.lastupdate = original.getLastUpdate();
        } else {
            this.utc = original.getTimeCalendar();
            this.latitud = original.getLatitud();
            this.longitud = original.getLongitud();
            this.altitud = original.getAltitud();
            this.velocidad = original.getVelocidad();
            this.cog = original.getCOG();
            this.nsat = original.getNSAT();
            this.io1 = original.getIo1();
            this.io2 = original.getIo2();
            this.io3 = original.getIo3();
            this.io4 = original.getIo4();
            this.hdop = original.getHdop();
            this.adc1 = original.getAdc();
            this.adc2 = original.getAdc2();
            this.power = original.getPower();
            this.bateria = original.getBateria();
            this.odometro = original.getOdometro();
            this.horometro = original.getHorometro();
            this.evento = original.getEvento();
            this.setTrailerId(original.getTrailerId());
            this.setTripTime(original.getTripTime());
            this.setHorometroInterno(original.getHorometroInterno());

        }
    }

    // Para INIT por BD
    public HazelCastobjGpsData(final boolean fromDB, final long imei,
            final String registro, final Calendar utc,
            final Calendar lastupdate, final long driverid,
            final double latitud, final double longitud, final double altitud,
            final double velocidad, final double cog, final double nsat,
            final double hdop, final double adc1, final double adc2,
            final double adc3, final double adc4, final double bateria,
            final int ignicion, final int io1, final int io2, final int io3,
            final int io4, final int power, final int antirobo,
            final int panico, final long odometro, final long horometro,
            final int evento) {
        this.imei = imei;
        this.driverId = driverid;
        this.panico = panico;
        this.antirobo = antirobo;
        this.ignicion = ignicion;
        this.now = registro;
        this.utc = utc;
        this.lastupdate = lastupdate;
        this.latitud = latitud;
        this.longitud = longitud;
        this.altitud = altitud;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
        this.cog = cog;
        this.nsat = nsat;
        this.io1 = io1;
        this.io2 = io2;
        this.io3 = io3;
        this.io4 = io4;
        this.hdop = hdop;
        this.adc1 = adc1;
        this.adc2 = adc2;
        this.adc3 = adc3;
        this.adc4 = adc4;
        this.power = power;
        this.bateria = bateria;
        this.horometro = horometro;
        this.odometro = odometro;
        this.setFromDB(fromDB);

    }

    @Override
    public void readData(final DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.utc = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            this.utc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                    .parse(arg0.readUTF()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            ReqInit.logger.fatal(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        this.lastupdate = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            this.lastupdate.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(arg0.readUTF()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            ReqInit.logger.fatal(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        this.now = arg0.readUTF();
        this.latitud = arg0.readDouble();
        this.longitud = arg0.readDouble();
        this.altitud = arg0.readDouble();
        this.velocidad = arg0.readDouble();
        this.cog = arg0.readDouble();
        this.nsat = arg0.readDouble();
        this.hdop = arg0.readDouble();
        this.adc1 = arg0.readDouble();
        this.adc2 = arg0.readDouble();
        this.adc3 = arg0.readDouble();
        this.adc4 = arg0.readDouble();
        this.bateria = arg0.readDouble();
        this.ignicion = arg0.readInt();
        this.io1 = arg0.readInt();
        this.io2 = arg0.readInt();
        this.io3 = arg0.readInt();
        this.io4 = arg0.readInt();
        this.power = arg0.readInt();
        this.antirobo = arg0.readInt();
        this.panico = arg0.readInt();
        this.imei = arg0.readLong();
        this.driverId = arg0.readLong();
        this.valid = arg0.readBoolean();
        this.odometro = arg0.readLong();
        this.horometro = arg0.readLong();
        this.evento = arg0.readInt();
        this.ip = arg0.readUTF();
        this.trailerId = arg0.readLong();
        this.tripTime = arg0.readLong();
        this.horometroInterno = arg0.readLong();
        this.ibutton2 = arg0.readLong();
        this.ibutton3 = arg0.readLong();
        this.ibutton4 = arg0.readLong();
        this.odometroInterno = arg0.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(final DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        arg0.writeUTF(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                .format(utc.getTime()));
        arg0.writeUTF(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                .format(lastupdate.getTime()));
        arg0.writeUTF(now);
        arg0.writeDouble(latitud);
        arg0.writeDouble(longitud);
        arg0.writeDouble(altitud);
        arg0.writeDouble(velocidad);
        arg0.writeDouble(cog);
        arg0.writeDouble(nsat);
        arg0.writeDouble(hdop);
        arg0.writeDouble(adc1);
        arg0.writeDouble(adc2);
        arg0.writeDouble(adc3);
        arg0.writeDouble(adc4);
        arg0.writeDouble(bateria);
        arg0.writeInt(ignicion);
        arg0.writeInt(io1);
        arg0.writeInt(io2);
        arg0.writeInt(io3);
        arg0.writeInt(io4);
        arg0.writeInt(power);
        arg0.writeInt(antirobo);
        arg0.writeInt(panico);
        arg0.writeLong(imei);
        arg0.writeLong(driverId);
        arg0.writeBoolean(valid);
        arg0.writeLong(odometro);
        arg0.writeLong(horometro);
        arg0.writeInt(evento);
        arg0.writeUTF(ip);
        arg0.writeLong(trailerId);
        arg0.writeLong(tripTime);
        arg0.writeLong(horometroInterno);
        arg0.writeLong(ibutton2);
        arg0.writeLong(ibutton3);
        arg0.writeLong(ibutton4);
        arg0.writeLong(odometroInterno);
    }

    public boolean isFromDB() {
        return fromDB;
    }

    public void setFromDB(boolean fromDB) {
        this.fromDB = fromDB;
    }

    public long getDeltaTime() {
        return delta_time;
    }

    private void setDelta_time(long delta_time) {
        this.delta_time = delta_time;
    }

    public double getAnteriorSog() {
        return anterior_sog;
    }

    private void setAnterior_sog(double anterior_sog) {
        this.anterior_sog = anterior_sog;
    }

    public double getAnterior_lon() {
        return anterior_lon;
    }

    private void setAnterior_lon(double anterior_lon) {
        this.anterior_lon = anterior_lon;
    }

    public double getAnterior_lat() {
        return anterior_lat;
    }

    private void setAnterior_lat(double anterior_lat) {
        this.anterior_lat = anterior_lat;
    }

    public double getAnteriorCog() {
        return anterior_cog;
    }

    private void setAnterior_cog(double anterior_cog) {
        this.anterior_cog = anterior_cog;
    }

    public double getAnteriorIgnicion() {
        return anterior_ignicion;
    }

    private void setAnterior_ignicion(double anterior_ignicion) {
        this.anterior_ignicion = anterior_ignicion;
    }

    public double getDeltaDist() {
        return delta_dist;
    }

    private void setDelta_dist(double delta_dist) {
        this.delta_dist = delta_dist;
    }

    public long getAnterior_odometro() {
        return anterior_odometro;
    }

    public long getAnterior_horometro() {
        return anterior_horometro;
    }

    public double getAdc3() {
        return adc3;
    }

    public void setAdc3(double adc3) {
        this.adc3 = adc3;
    }

    public double getAdc4() {
        return adc4;
    }

    public void setAdc4(double adc4) {
        this.adc4 = adc4;
    }

    public long getTrailerId() {
        return trailerId;
    }

    public void setTrailerId(long trailerId) {
        this.trailerId = trailerId;
    }

    public long getTripTime() {
        return tripTime;
    }

    public void setTripTime(long tripTime) {
        this.tripTime = tripTime;
    }

    public long getIbutton2() {
        return ibutton2;
    }

    public void setIbutton2(long ibutton2) {
        this.ibutton2 = ibutton2;
    }

    public long getIbutton3() {
        return ibutton3;
    }

    public void setIbutton3(long ibutton3) {
        this.ibutton3 = ibutton3;
    }

    public long getIbutton4() {
        return ibutton4;
    }

    public void setIbutton4(long ibutton4) {
        this.ibutton4 = ibutton4;
    }

    public long getOdometroInterno() {
        return odometroInterno;
    }

    public void setOdometroInterno(long odometroInterno) {
        this.odometroInterno = odometroInterno;
    }

}
```

We are aware that we are using and older version of hazelcast but upgrade it is not an option yet, we want to know if there is a code issue first. Could you please help me to find the issue ?